# Term for "the story referred to by the title of the collection"

Tags: phrase-requests

Many short story collections are titled something like *Foobar and Other Stories*.  Suppose I am writing a review of such a collection and want to refer to the story entitled "Foobar".  I wish to say something like

> The [story referred to by the title], "Foobar", is the highlight of the collection.

What term or phrase can I use in place of "story referred to by the title"?

If Foobar were a character, I would use the adjective "eponymous", e.g.
"The eponymous Foobar and his sidekick Baz must embark on a quest to...".  But this doesn't seem quite right when the entity is a story title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I just remembered the phrase I was looking for: "title story".

Comment: The adjectival form is *titular*.

Comment: @Marthaª Perhaps, but I didn't want to use that for two reasons: (a) it has a distracting second meaning of "in name only", and (b) I always associate it with "titular counselor", which makes me think of Akaky Akakievich, which lends the adjective a sort of foolishness in my eyes.

Comment: @Marthaª Also, [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/titular#Adjective) lists this usage of "titular" as proscribed, I'm not sure by whom.